# OnsenUI - Icon in the InputBox Placeholder?

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

Using Monaca/Onsen-UI - but struggle to understand the syntax of an input box whereby I want an icon placed in the [placeholder].

The following example from [] works, showing an 'email' type icon - which is clearly the result of [&#xf0e0], but I don't understand to what that relates.  Generally for OnsenUI i'd use a `<i>` (etc).

Can someone please explain to what the [&#xf0e0] that refers and how I find out what the icon I want to use is...?

SAMPLE:

```
<input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder=" &#xf0e0;  Notes" value="">
```

Answer (score -1):

&#xf0e0 - it is ASCII code of some icon from FontAwesome font. You may use this list to find symbol you need [HERE](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).